# Secure solution to hidden forms

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<? if ($cur_post['poster_id'] == $forum_user['id']) { ?>
  <div class="txt-box textarea required">
  <label for="fld<?php echo ++ $forum_page['fld_count'] ?>"><span><?php echo $lang_post['Write message'] ?>  <em><?php echo $lang_common['Required'] ?></em></span></label>
  <div class="txt-input"><span class="fld-input"><textarea id="fld<?php echo $forum_page['fld_count'] ?>" name="req_message" rows="14" cols="95"><?php echo forum_htmlencode(isset($_POST['req_message']) ? $message : $cur_post['message']) ?></textarea></span></div>
 </div>
</div>
  <? }
else { ?>

<? } ?>
```

I need a more secure solution to hidden forms, because currently with this code when I press submit (as an admin) it says I must enter a value for the written message.
I can bypass this using hidden forms under the `ELSE` bit - but people with any knowledge can just bypass this using Inspect Element or Firebug and then post that value.

I need a more secure solution to this, so that people cannot edit Hidden forms. Do I post the old variable somehow to the form?

It's for a PunBB page (edit.php): http://punbb.informer.com/svn/punbb/tags/punbb-1.3.3/edit.php (original).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is always an interesting problem.

I suggest storing private data in the users $_SESSION with an index unique to the form + page call.  I just came into a similar problem at work where I was starting to pass way too much private data through hidden form fields.  Now I simply pass a unique id which I use to index the specific private form data in the session.

It's not a 100% solution.  Storing the data in the session rather than in the form means a stale form can timeout (ie if the session is killed/timed out), but it's a worth while trade off I think.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Not entirely sure I want this, but anyhow.

Comment: @Dean - Care to elaborate on what you DO want then?

Comment: @Craige I replied to Bryan M. I only want the Admins to be able to edit the Topic Title and nothing else, unless the Admin made the topic.

If I remove the forms for the else bit, it returns an error stating I must enter something in the message field (write field).

Comment: Yes, that is not a form problem.  This is a logic problem with the processing page.  The processing page does not seem to be smart enough to know handle this.

Comment: Hmm, thats what I thought... but its handling the whole form. When you click submit it does the whole form (title+message). I need it to only do the title if its an admin.. I guess I need to look elsewhere for a paid dev.

Comment: Just my two cents about the $_SESSION storing thing: it's just fine imo, but there is the timeout issue.  The only solution is to increase the timeout, but if that's not viable, you have to store to a DB/file, etc (using similar indexing for instance).  If that's not feasible either, you're really SOL.  Sorry that this is a bit off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. Are you trying to control how the form renders, or trying to figure out how to add 'sensitive' data the a form?

First, if you're worried about what parts of the form are being rendered on the page, anything in the `else` clause would only render if the conditions in the `if` clause were not true. The `else` is not 'hiding' part of the form.

Second, there is no such thing as a 'secure' client-side form. Generally speaking, you cannot control what data is submitted to your application, and anyone can submit any POST or GET data they want. Instead you have to handle it on the server-side by properly filtering to ensure that a user has the proper authorization to do what they're trying to do. It sounds like you need to require the user to identify as an admin when the form is processed (most likely through session data).

Comment: Basically, I want the normal user to be able to edit any field (providing they posted the topic) and Admins can only edit the Topic Title, but nothing else.
So admins can ONLY modify the topic title, and nothing else. I hope I make sense.
It looks as though I cannot use just this one page for this, I would need to create another for editing the topic title. I dont need a session, I just want the default value of the message left in there.

Comment: Based on your other comments, what you need shouldn't be hard in theory, but if you're modifying third-party code that doesn't support that logic by default, it could get complicated . If you're not feeling like you have the experience to tackle this, it shouldn't be too hard for a dev.